# Android: java.land.NoSuchFieldError after update to SDK 23

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-6.0-marshmallow

I updated to SDK 23 and updated the gradle.build to API 23, support library to 23.0.0, etc and am now getting the following error when trying to run the app (compiles just fine).

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No instance field mFragments of type Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentManagerImpl; in class Landroid/support/v4/app/Watson; or its superclasses (declaration of 'android.support.v4.app.Watson' appears in /data/app/com.my.app-1/base.apk)
            at android.support.v4.app.Watson.onCreatePanelMenu(Watson.java:50)
            at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlock.java:560)
            at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:64)
            at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:164)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:548)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:917)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:258)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

I reverted back to API 22 on everything and still get the error.

Comment: Why are you still using ABS, you should have migrated to the actual support library actionbar or better yet `Toolbar` by now

Comment: Yeah, I know. My new app is API 21 and on, but I still am supporting my old app and don't want to spend the time to implement AppCompat (tried once, got very messy).

Comment: I do believe something wrong happens in Android 6.0 Preview and Android Studio 1.4.1.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I did the some thing as you did ,
but I found gradle can solve dependencies,
in External Libraries i cannot find support-v4-23.0.0,support-v7-23.0.0 and other lib which the version is 23.0.0.
then I reverted back to compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0',
the problem solver @mraviator

Comment: Works for me as well, even though when using com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 there a warning "This support library should not use a lower version than the targetSDKVersion (23)

Comment: if updates  compileSdkVersion  to 23,the problem also can be solve.

Comment: switching back to com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 also worked for me

Comment: I had another library with `com.android.support:support-v4:+`, which caused the latest version to be used. Setting that to the specific version I was using in my main project fixed the issue for me.

Comment: It isn't working for me. Can you tell me what is your version of `buildToolsVersion` now? I'm using `HoloEverywhere` and `ABS`

Comment: My buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

Comment: Version 23 is the tipping point as after that version Android became more like iOS

Answer (score 12):

Thank you @zmarties for the answer , I want to add the details and links

1. Remove 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar' from gradle
2. Download actionbarsherlock module from  [this link](http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html)!
3. Verify that you have 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0' or 23
4. Open the actionbarsherlock module src change FloatMath to Math in AnimatorProxy.java
5. Open the actionbarsherlock module src  create variable fragments in class level scope as **FragmentManagerImpl fragments = (FragmentManagerImpl) this.getSupportFragmentManager();** in Watson.java
6. Replace all **mFragments occurrence with fragments** variable

Thank you for the above answers .

Comment: How to integrate the download actionbarsherlock module with my Android studio project?

Comment: In my version of the ActionBarSherlock the edit had to be done on _ActionBarSherlockTrojanHorse.java instead of Watson.java

Answer (score 6):

Using google play services version 8.1.0 instead of 8.4.0 solved on my side

Comment: I could achieve it by using the com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 and Google play services 8.1.0.

Answer (score 3):

I found that I could build ActionBarSherlock using SDK 23 if I made the following two sets of changes:

- in AnimatorProxy.java, replace `FloatMath` calls with their corresponding `Math` calls
- in Watson.java, replace the use of the `mFragments` field with a local variable `fragments` initialized via `getActiveFragments(null)`, and then change the `mFragment` references to use the local variable

Comment: Nice, do you have this patches published anywhere please?

Comment: No - I don't make sufficient use of ActionBarSherlock that I'd consider these changes sufficiently tested to release as a real patch.  As I said, they allowed the code to compile, and that was enough for me to make further progress with my porting efforts.

Comment: >In Watson.java, replace the use of the mFragments field with a local variable fragments initialized via >getActiveFragments(null), and then change the mFragment references to use the local variable

According to this way, may I know the sample code about how to change it. I dont see local variable fragments inside Watson.java in actionbarSherlock library. And I also dont see getActiveFragment(null) method. Could you please suggest me?

Comment: Now I found the way. We use support library v4 23 and add new fragments variable as FragmentManagerImpl fragments = (FragmentManagerImpl) mFragments.getSupportFragmentManager();

Comment: zmarties I do not understand what to do in Watson.java, could you explain me what should I have to do to fix it please. I just need to use support-v4:23+ with action bar sherlock.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the theme view in the main layout from the design tab? 
Try changing it again to a Sherlock theme view at the design tab.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem when import project eclipse to Android Studio

This is best solution for me

I found that I could build ActionBarSherlock using SDK 23 if I made the following two sets of changes:

in AnimatorProxy.java, replace FloatMath calls with their corresponding Math calls -  i change FloatMath  - to Math

in Waston Class i had the error - **mFragments.isadded**
So,
i replace the follow code instead of checking

**mFragments.isadded != null**

to

**mFragments.getActiveFragments(mCreatedMenus)**

everywher when it required

i had solve these issues.