# Issue building actionbarsherlock with latest android support v4 library (version 23)

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library

I updated my support v4 library to latest version 23 and also updated the jar for the same in my actionbarsherlock library and a build issue started to come. Watson.java shows multiple errors.

It just doesn't allow me to take the latest (version 23) support v4 jar and use with the actionbarsherlock library source code for building the library. As a result, I am forced to use an older copy of the support v4 in the lib folder of actionbarsherlock and then build and add this library in other projects.

Also as a result none of my projects can use the latest v4 support library due to multiple version issue, that would occur.

Please suggest a solution..

Comment: Time to migrate the AppCompat

Comment: I know :) Do you have a complete list of things that one needs to follow for this migration? I do see a webpage explaining this, but doesn't seem to cover everything - http://www.grokkingandroid.com/migrating-actionbarsherlock-actionbarcompat/

Answer (score 0):

I am now having the same problem, there are a couple solutions here [Android: java.land.NoSuchFieldError after update to SDK 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32078602/android-java-land-nosuchfielderror-after-update-to-sdk-23)

Also, the link you posted about updating to AppCompat is not actually about updating to AppCompat but ActionBarCompat which is now deprecated.

To update to AppCompat, as a light guide:

- download the AppCompat package
- change Activity to AppCompatActivity
- Change any SherlockFragment etc to normal Fragment and be sure to use the V4 library and not the default Android.App
- Use the support library where needed ie SupportFragmentManager and SupportActionBar etc. If you are getting errors somewhere, check if it has a Support alternative.
- Change your styles to implement Theme.AppCompat. Your app will crash if you do not do this.

There will be other errors of course that you will have to work through that are specific to your project.